# Facebook: Multiple Like Buttons and Custom Meta Tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

I'm having problems with the FB like Button. I've one button in my headers with href to my site root, in every page, so the metatags (og:image, og:title: og:type, etc..) are optimized to index.php or root page..

Now, in the post or news pages, I have articles with their own button, and the meta tags they must change..

is there any possibility to set this buttons config in each button? I'm trying to not use iframes! I think with an iframe with the button to my root page, maybe works, but is not the best practice!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Because as you know Facebook uses Open Graph meta tags and pages have unique meta tags.

The only thing you can do is create a page for your global website (for example, create a FB fan page of mysite.com) and use the Page Plugin :

```
<fb:fan profile_id="222496653719" href="http://www.facebook.com/mysite" stream="0" connections="1" logobar="0" width="260" height="100"></fb:fan>
```

By the way, it would be strange to "like a website" as you want to do. Now Facebook behaviour is to "share an article" and "like a page (of a website or whatever)".

And for your posts the standard Like Plugin :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like href="YOURSPECIFICPOSTURL" layout="button_count" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was confused. I put into the fb:url the url of my page, instead of the url of my fan page! And this is best because every like is count on my fb page to.. Thanks!